# Calling singleton object initiated from nib

Tags: objective-c, object, init, alloc

I have an object which is initiated in my nib file. I want it to be a singleton but also accessible from code through `[myClass sharedInstance];`. Right now I have this:

```
static myClass *singleton = nil;

@implementation myClass
+ (myClass *)sharedInstance
{
    if (!singleton) singleton = [[self class] new];
    return singleton;
}

+ (id)alloc
{
    return [self sharedInstance];
}

- (id)init 
{ 
    if ([self class] != nil)
        self = [super init])
    return self; 
} 
@end
```

But `alloc` never gets called.

Comment: I'm not sure why your `alloc` method doesn't get called (maybe you need to override `allocWithZone:` as well), but isn't this going to be problematic anyway? When `alloc` calls `sharedInstance`, that's going to result in another call to `alloc`, and so on infinitely.

Comment: It looks like I indeed need allocWithZone: and that I have an infinite loop.

Comment: To solve the infinite loop, you could have a flag variable that indicated whether the singleton was in the process of being created. `sharedInstance` would set it, and `alloc` would check it. If it was set, `alloc` would call `[super alloc]`.

Comment: I think I found a better alternative. At the end of http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SingletonDesignPattern

Answer (score 1):

Solved. See the end of http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SingletonDesignPattern